# On the homotopy relation between two maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f,g:X\longrightarrow X$ be two continuous maps.   Recall that $f$
 and $g$ are homotopic if there exists a continuous map $F:X\times I\longrightarrow X$ so that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$.

Is there a known result (in connection to homotopy or homology groups) from which we can obtain $f\simeq g$?

Comment: Are you asking is there a general approach as to how to show that two maps are homotopic?

Comment: @RichoKicked800goals Not in general. I just want to know that whether there is  a  known theorem about it or not. For example, if  $\pi_i (f)=\pi_i (g)$ for all $i$, then $f\simeq g$?

Comment: @M.Ramana No, this is not true. Take any non-contractible space with trivial homotopy and homology groups, e.g. open long line. Then it has non-homotopic maps $X\to X$ (namely the identity and a constant map) but they obviously induce the same map on both homotopy and homology groups (being all trivial).

Comment: @freakish Thank you very much for the comment. Indeed my question is that: is there any algebraic result (in term of homotopy and homology groups like above) from which one can conclude $f\simeq g$?

Comment: For example, by the Withehead Theorem, if $X$ and $Y$ be two CW-complexes and $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ a continuous map so that $\pi_i (f)$ is an isomorphism for all $i$, then $X \simeq Y$ through $f$. Is there any similar result for maps?

Comment: @M.Ramana Non-homotopic maps between CW-complexes may generate the same homomorphisms. And in general setup your question is probably doomed for negative answer. You may want to read this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2672/whitehead-for-maps especially the third answer by Tim Campion.

Comment: @freakish Thank you so much for your help. The link is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homotopy classification of maps $X \to Y$ is clearly related to that of finding the path components of the function space $Y^X$.

However for some practical answers related to CW-complexes and cohomology I refer you to

Ellis, G.J.
Homotopy classification the J.H.C. Whitehead way.
Exposition. Math. 6~(2) (1988) 97--110.

A pdf is available [here](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/Ellis-homclass.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.